# overflow-x scroll and overflow-y visible

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a case in which i have to show the content horizontally with `overflow-x:scroll;`.

Now in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/qM45U/4/) the  first block has `overflow-y:scroll;` which gives a scroll and user is able to scroll the content. Where as in the second block user is not able to scroll the content. I want an output this way in the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oVfU.png), where user can scroll horizontally and see the content. 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oVfU.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an inner container for your second block and give it a width.

```
<div class="test2"><div>dfdsfdsfds</div></div>
```

and

```
.test2 div {
    width: 600px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qM45U/8/

The reason for this is that by default, when test reached it's width it will word wrap whereas within the y-axis it will just increase the height of the container (if allowed).  You could just set white-space to nowrap but then you'd end up with the longest single line of text in the world :)

Comment: the content which should be wrapped for me is dynamic... will there be any javascript solution

Answer (score 1):

Give your second div a child div to wrap the content that has the same height but a bigger width. Then style it:

```
.test2 div {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qM45U/6/)**